# Angular 7 correctly upload doc/docx file

Tags: file-upload, angular7, angular-input

I'm having troubles uploading doc and docx files, because I can't get the right type of file when converting it to base64. This is my input:

```
  <input
    accept=".pdf,.txt,.doc,.docx"
    type="file"
    (change)="onNativeInputFileSelect($event)"
    #inputFile
    hidden
  />
```

In my method I do this:

```
  onNativeInputFileSelect(event) {
    if (event.target.value) {
      const file: File = event.target.files[0];
      this.changeFile(file).then((base64: string): any => {
        this.attachment.content= base64;
        this.uploadFile(this.attachment);
      });
    }
  }
```

then in "uploadFile" I send the file to server as base 64 string.
The `changeFile` methods is this:

```
  changeFile(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    });
  }
```

This works fine for pdf or txt files, but when I upload .doc or .docx files I get this base64 string:

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,0M8R4KGxGuEAA[...]
```

while for pdf I correctly have:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMS
```

This means that when I try to download the file I don't get the correct type, because I have application/octet-stream, and so I can't put the right extension to the file.
I've tried by passing to the `accept` property of input component this:

```
application/msword,application/pdf,text/plain,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

But nothing changed and the Window's file chooser suggested me only .pdf and .txt files

**EDIT**

[This is a working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-jbrecy?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: This is working fine on my mac.

"CONTENUTO
data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,UEsDBB...."

Answer (score 0):

I get "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,UEsDBB[...]" for docx and "data:application/msword;base64,0M8R4KGxGuv[...]" for doc file.

Comment: On the stackblitz I've shared?

Comment: Yes, I copied them from the log